# Grouping Data using

Tags: php, xml

i am drawing a blank on this one and need some help. I have a database with metrics and I am trying to create a line chart. It involves grouping, or  merging, the records based on the ID of the metric so I can then loop over and then do a sub loop on the values to generate the XML to produce the chart using PHP.

For example my recordset:

```
MetricID, Metric Name, Quarter,  Year, Value

1   Total Calls 1   2011-01-01  22403.00

1   Total Calls 2   2011-01-01  22366.00

1   Total Calls 3   2011-01-01  34456.00

1   Total Calls 4   2011-01-01  36456.00

1   Total Calls 1   2012-01-01  38456.00

1   Total Calls 2   2012-01-01  33256.00

1   Total Calls 3   2012-01-01  35456.00

1   Total Calls 4   2012-01-01  30456.00

2   Total Referrals 1   2011-01-01  9668.00

2   Total Referrals 2   2011-01-01  9154.00

2   Total Referrals 3   2011-01-01  10445.00,

2   Total Referrals 4   2011-01-01  12445.00

2   Total Referrals 1   2012-01-01  12845.00

2   Total Referrals 2   2012-01-01  10145.00

2   Total Referrals 3   2012-01-01  10445.00

2   Total Referrals 4   2012-01-01  12445.00
```

I need to loop over first the Total Calls to do a sub loop for the values, then loop over the Total Referrals, doing a sub loop of its values. Since the list is variable, I never know how many distince metric IDs I might get, 1 to 4.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the expected output? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one responded, here is A answer:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    if ($i != $row->metricID) {
        print $row->mTitle."<br />";
        $i = $row->metricID;
    }
    print $row->value."<br />";
}
```